Go channel sometimes not receiving the last value
I'm currently learning go channels, and I'm trying out this piece of code. It creates 10 goroutines which sends a 1000 1s each to a channel. Then another go routine receives it and adds it to a counter. I also used WaitGroups to make sure the goroutines are finished before printing the results.
Code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var counter int

    fmt.Println("\nWithout Channels -------")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
                // to simulate race condition
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(1))
                counter++
            }
        }()
    }

    runtime.Gosched()

    fmt.Println("Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter:", counter)

    fmt.Println("\nWith Channels -------")
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        WithChannels()
    }
}

func WithChannels() {
    var counter int
    ch := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // var wg2 sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(1))
                ch <- 1
            }
        }()
    }

    // wg2.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for {
            increment, ok := <-ch
            if !ok {
                // channel closed, break
                break
            }
            counter += increment
        }
        // wg2.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    // wg2.Wait()
    // time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter:", counter)
    close(ch)
}


Output:
Without Channels -------
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 139

With Channels -------
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 9999
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 10000
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 9999
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 10000
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 10000
Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter: 9999
...

I expect the counter be 10,000 every time I run it, however it seems like sometimes it is not receiving the last value. I've tried adding another WaitGroup for the receiving goroutine (seen in comments), but it causes a deadlock.
Am I doing something wrong here?

You're receiving from the channel in a goroutine but never waiting for it to finish its work. You could instead use a goroutine for waiting on the completion of the senders and closing the channel, and then just receive from the channel in the main goroutine.
func WithChannels() {
    var counter int
    ch := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(1))
                ch <- 1
            }
        }()
    }

    // Use a goroutine to wait for all the senders to complete and then close the channel.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    // Receive from the channel until it's closed.
    for {
        increment, ok := <-ch
        if !ok {
            // channel closed, break
            break
        }
        counter += increment
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Expected counter: 10000, Actual counter:", counter)
}


Ohh i see. So is the reason the wait & close is done in another go routine so that it doesn't block the receiver in the main thread? Since then I've found out sending/recceiving on a non-buffered channel blocks the thread if there is no other side & that i should close the channel after all the senders are done. So it's making a bit more sense now. Thanks for the answer!
